# Clicking noise gets better with water

Tags: mountain-bike, crankset, noise

So here's my latest video checking the casette, you don't have to watch it all.

This is the old video when running:

My question is why in the world the problem does gets affected so much with water?... not oil; but water, I literally put a shiton of water on the casette and the bike today was fine and only clicked twice, I was thinking if it was dirt but how could dirt cause such effect? I could understand a grit sound, but a click, I am confused at this point.

Comment: Have you taken the cassette off and checked the freehub out?

Comment: The sound in the top video is a spoke "twanging".  The sound in the bottom video is coming from the chain.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I was holding all the spokes at some point and it remained doing it. And I'm sure the sound comes from the casette area.

Comment: Why did it get so well with water, that's my main question.

Comment: Water is acting as a (poor) lubricant, that's why the sounds change when its drenched.  Not a long term solution though.

Comment: Water deadens sounds.

Comment: @Criggie I have put a lot of lubricant, and it doesn't work, but water does; and usually when that happens even when it'd still click creak rarely, it takes a while before it comes back. maybe 5 days, it should take less time as the water should've dried up.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that you have oval bearings in the freewheel or even a cracked pawl, even though you say the bike is new this does happen. Take the bike back to where ever you purchased it an ask them to replace it as faulty.

In the second video I also think the chain is making the noise but this maybe wrong as I'm hearing the sound wrongly. Turn the bike upside down though and pedal backwards slowly. Watch the chain links as they travel over the freewheel as you may notice that there are tight links here, they will show up as they lift when they travel over the freewheel. If you find any loosen them up with a chain link tool.

Comment: The first and the second sound are the same, for some reason the sound varies a lot; the chain wasn't stiff, and even so it was replaced and it would still make the sound, the sound came from the freewheel area.